# Duplicate testing in Excel

Tags: excel, duplicates, exact-match

I need an excel formular to do advance Exact match and identify same record or different record

I have over 100,000 rows.
I have been able to test for duplicate but I want to further check using column A1 and A2; let me know if B1 and B2 are same name but skip to test A3 and A4 to tell me if B3 and B4 are the same. I don't want it to test A2 and A3 because I know they are different.

I need a formular in Excel without vba to achieve this

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 100000 | Depe |
| 100000 | Depe |
| 200000 | June |
| -------- | -------- |
| 200000 | Baby |
| 200000 | Boy |
| 300000 | May |
| -------- | -------- |
| 300000 | Book |
|  |  |

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have attempted, and also what you expect the result to look like. It might be helpful to  take the [Two Minute Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Then read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

In cell C1 place this formula

```
=IF((A1=A2)*(B1=B2),"PAIR","")
```

press Enter. Then select C1 and C2, after drag down till the end of the column of data.

**Result**

[image]

Remark: If you insert/delete rows in the data need to copy down again C1-C2, because the inserted/deleted row destroy the pairing after action.